# PHP & SQL WHERE (changing variable)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Good Day, i'm struggling with this code.. 
The result "10" is set $fod but this needs to be replaced to display the called row's id so that the SQL WHERE can list the correct data inside the relevant row. See Image for the Result i'm getting.

[See Current Result and Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSCpP.png)
As you can see i need ROW ID 10 to display 10's items and ROW ID 11 to display 11's items. Please assist me, how can i call these rows to display correctly?
Calling function:
Controller.php

```
$data['order_list'] = $this->product->data_ordershalf();
$fod = 10;
$data['order_listfull'] = $this->product->data_ordersfull($fod);
```

Functions.php:

```
function data_ordershalf(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->join('order_detail', 'order_detail.orderid=orders.id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('customers', 'customers.id=orders.customerid', 'left');
    $this->db->join('testshop_products', 'testshop_products.product_id=order_detail.productid', 'left');
    $this->db->from('orders');
    $this->db->group_by('orderid');
    $rs = $this->db->get();
    return $rs->result_array();
}
function data_ordersfull($fod){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->join('orders', 'orders.id=order_detail.orderid', 'left');
    $this->db->join('testshop_products', 'testshop_products.product_id=order_detail.productid', 'left');
    $this->db->from('order_detail');
    $this->db->where('orderid',$fod);
    $rs = $this->db->get();
    return $rs->result_array();
```

View.php:

```
<?php if(!$order_list){ ?>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="7"><center>No orders placed</center></th>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<?php } else { $sr = 1; ?>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach( $order_list as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></th>
        <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <?php foreach( $order_listfull as $row2) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><?php echo $row2['id']; ?></th>
                    <td><?php echo $row2['product_name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row2['quantity']; ?></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row2['price']; ?></td>
                 </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $row['quantity']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create helper and put following  function it.

```
function data_ordersfull($fod){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->join('orders', 'orders.id=order_detail.orderid', 'left');
    $this->db->join('testshop_products', 'testshop_products.product_id=order_detail.productid', 'left');
    $this->db->from('order_detail');
    $this->db->where('orderid',$fod);
    $rs = $this->db->get();
    return $rs->result_array();
}
```

====================View.php======================================

```
<?php if(!$order_list){ ?>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th colspan="7"><center>No orders placed</center></th>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            <?php } else { $sr = 1; ?>
            <tbody>
              <?php foreach( $order_list as $row) { 
$order_listfull=data_ordersfull($row['id']);
?>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></th>
                <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                <td><table>
              <?php foreach( $order_listfull as $row2) { ?>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row"><?php echo $row2['id']; ?></th>
                <td><?php echo $row2['product_name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row2['quantity']; ?></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><?php echo $row2['price']; ?></td>

              </tr>
              <?php } ?></table></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['quantity']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>

                  </tr>
                  <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
                <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved everything! I just needed to modify this part:

$order_listfull=$this->product->data_ordersfull($row['id']);

Answer (score 0):

```
function data_ordershalf(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('orders');
    $this->db->join('order_detail', 'order_detail.orderid=orders.id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('customers', 'customers.id=orders.customerid', 'left');
    $this->db->join('testshop_products', 'testshop_products.product_id=order_detail.productid', 'left');
    $this->db->group_by('order_detail.orderid');
    $rs = $this->db->get();
    return $rs->result_array();
}
function data_ordersfull($fod){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('order_detail');
    $this->db->join('orders', 'orders.id=order_detail.orderid', 'left');
    $this->db->join('testshop_products', 'testshop_products.product_id=order_detail.productid', 'left');
    $this->db->where('order_detail.orderid',$fod);
    $rs = $this->db->get();
    return $rs->result_array();
```